# Why does this query return "System.NotImplementedException"?

Tags: c#

While I debug this query, I got error "Static Members" & "Non-public members".
What is the wrong in below query:

```
var existingShippingId = shippingSeriesRepository
    .FilterBy(sid => shippingId == sid.ShippingId)
    .FirstOrDefault(); //this working fine without error

var filtered = positioningPlanRepository
                    .FilterBy(x => x.ShippingSerieses.Contains(existingShippingId))
                    .GroupBy(x => x.DeliveryDate)
                    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                    .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.PlanId));
```

when I clicked detail information error , I got this message :

> System.NotImplementedException = error CS0119: 'NotImplementedException' is a type, which is not valid in the given context new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView>(filtered).Items, hidden = 'new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView>(filtered).Items' threw an exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException'

Comment: *"I got error "Static Members" & "Non-public members""* this isn't an error message.

Comment: I got the error which I mentioned above, when I click error explanation is : System.NotImplementedException = error CS0119: 'NotImplementedException' is a type, which is not valid in the given context new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>(filtered).Items, hidden = 'new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>(filtered).Items' threw an exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException'

Comment: Where are you getting the "Static Members" & "Non-public members" error? That makes no sense. What is `FilterBy`? Which part of your Linq query is giving you that error?

Comment: When I debug (ctr+alt +p) I see that two error which I mentioned above. `FilterBy` part is working after `FilterBy` nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, as far as I understood this query `Select (x => x.Select(y =>` ,  works in memory , and NHibarnate does not understand.
I added `ToList()` end of the query and it worked.

```
var filtered = positioningPlanRepository
                .FilterBy(x => x.ShippingSerieses.Contains(existingShippingId)).ToList()
                .GroupBy(x => x.DeliveryDate)
                .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.PlanId));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not implemented a Select() method in the class of x in the following line:

```
.Select(x => x.Select(y => y.PlanId));
```

I think the correct version is:

```
.Select(x => x.PlanId);
```